# How to define three or more elements to be different from each other

Tags: logic, terminology

Lets say we have three elements $a, b, c$ from a set $S$: $a,b,c\in{S}$.

We want to specify that all the three elements are different from each other.

My experience suggests to me that it is commonly done with $a\neq{b}\neq{c}$. Now, I just realize that in my opinion this just means that $b$ is different from both $a$ and $c$, but it does not say anything about the relationship between $a$ and $c$.

In fact, suppose actually $a=c$ and $a\neq{b}$ and $c\neq{b}$. The previous expression is satisfied to me.

To "complete" the chain of differences I think that the correct rigorous way to express the difference of all the three elements should be $a\neq{b}\neq{c}\neq{a}$. This is the correct way to say that there are no "duplicates" among the three elements. So the other expression is just of common use, but actually not properly correct.

Am I wrong?

Comment: Correct: equality is *transitive* while disequality is not.

Comment: Words are better: The phrase "$a,b,c$ are distinct" implies no two are equal -- it's more readable, and the meaning is instantly understood. If done with pairwise "$\ne$" relations, then for $n$ variables, you would need $\binom{n}{2}$ such relations -- awkward, to say the least.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure there's a particularly good way to say this with symbols. Normally you'd just say "Let $a,b,c\in S$ be pairwise distinct" or "Let $a,b,c$ be pairwise distinct elements of $S$. ('Pairwise distinct' just means all the pairs of elements are different, ie $a\neq b$, $a\neq c$ and $b\neq c$; less formally you could just say 'distinct'.)

Comment: Thank you for the good hint, but my question was specifically whether that way to say it in symbols is formally correct or not rather than the "best" way to say it. The comment from @Mauro ALLEGRANZA is actually the answer I was looking for